# How can I create a different layout between cart.liquid and ajax-cart-template.liquid using Timber framework for Shopify

Tags: ajax, shopify, cart

I’m wondering if you could help me with a problem I’m facing with the Ajaxify cart for my theme using the [Timber framework](http://shopify.github.io/Timber/#ajax-cart).

My design has a slightly different layout of content between my standard cart page (cart.liquid template) and the ajaxify pop-out quick cart that I want to create. I’m a bit confused as to how you remove & add certain elements, for example when I move the product title to go above my product image nothing changes…

Am I right in thinking that the ajaxify script is pulling in the /cart form content from the cart.liquid template, if so am I able to create an additional different form in a template for my ajax quick cart?

How to achieve this? It is possible to have a different layout between the cart and the quick cart?

Comment: cart.liquid is `your /cart template. If you are using the Ajaxify Cart plugin,
  your form (with action="/cart") layout will be used in the drawer/modal.` 
AFAIK that means that cart.liquid will be used in both spots. However, you can also change around some aspects in the ajax-cart-template.liquid, though it looks like you can only change parts of the form.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I essentially need to switch the order of a few elements and remove a few things such as the shipping calculator. If I wanted to do this would all of that need to be done in the ajax-cart-template.liquid file?

Comment: I haven't actually managed to change anything using the ajax-cart-template.liquid, but I imagine that you could use some sort of `if` statement in the cart.liquid page. This isn't real code, but something like `{% if this page is cart.html %} *things for cart page only* {% endif %}`

Comment: I posted the same question on the Shopify Timber github and Carson, the creator of Timber replied with this answer... https://github.com/Shopify/Timber/issues/350  I haven't tried it yet but it sounds promising and I think is the solution I need. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Glad you got a solution! He'd know wayyy more about it than I do :)